# What is "while true do skip"

Tags: java, loops, while-loop, pseudocode, skip

Im working on programming solutions to mutexes and semaphores. Most loops I've dealt with here are:

```
while(true)
{
/* do nothing*/
}
```

I came across some pseudocode for an algorithm where they have

```
while choosing[i] do skip ;
```

(`choosing` is an array of booleans)

So is `do skip` the same as "dont do anything"?

I'm going to implement the psuedocode in java.

Answer (score 1):

use `continue`

```
while(true)
{

//condition
 continue;
}
```

See oracle docs on [Branching Statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html)

> The continue statement skips the current iteration of a for, while , or do-while loop.

See the example given by Oracle

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {

        String searchMe = "peter piper picked a " + "peck of pickled peppers";
        int max = searchMe.length();
        int numPs = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < max; i++) {
            // interested only in p's
            if (searchMe.charAt(i) != 'p')
                continue;

            // process p's
            numPs++;
        }
        System.out.println("Found " + numPs + " p's in the string.");
    }
```

[Here is the full demo code](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/examples/ContinueDemo.java)

Comment: Isn't this an infinite loop ?

Answer (score 0):

I think it is more like:

```
if(! choosing[i]) {
      //Do some logic
}
```

Comment: Thanks that makes sense. This is essentially `continue`. I just dont see why they would have `do skip` because in the psuedocode there is no other logic that comes afterwards within the `while` loop.